# Locate result of repository layer to DTO Object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I need to get count and sum of my ObjectEntity in one Query form Repository Layer. Count is a Long value, but sum is Double value. It possible to locate  result in one DTO Object from Repository method or locate it  numeric list object e.g. List ?
Query method look like below

```
@Query(value = "Select count(f), sum(f.valueToPay) from ObjectEntity f ")
    Object[]  getData();
```

POJO Object

```
@Data
public class ObjectDTO {

    Double value;
    Long quantity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you just need the results of the query to go into an object that will give you meaningful and consistent variable names.

All you should need to do is Change Object[] to ObjectDTO so that you have

```
@Query(value = "Select count(f), sum(f.valueToPay) from ObjectEntity f ")
ObjectDTO  getData();
```

Right now you are mapping to an object array instead of the actual object you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [JPQL Constructor Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor):

```
@Query(value = "Select NEW com.company.pathToYourDto.ObjectDTO(count(f), sum(f.valueToPay)) from ObjectEntity f ")
ObjectDTO  getData();
```